# Giving a specific position to cursor in terminal (up-line) after previous line breaks

Tags: python, terminal, position, reverse, line-breaks

I am working on a script to show in the terminal an empty matrix with dot representing all the elements to be filled. Then, I want to ask to the user which element he wants to select for each position.

I had some issues that I couldn't solve with the code given by the professor:
[Printing string elements on terminal at certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773806/printing-string-elements-on-terminal-at-certain-position).

I have found another way by writting the following code:

```
for y in range(0, nbLines):
    for x in range(0, nbColumns):
        print("{0}\t".replace('\t', ' ' * 5).format('.'), end='')
        if x == nbColumns -1:
            print('')
            print("\n")
```

Now, I would like to know if there is a possibility to "go back" to the initial position with my first dot to ask the user to select each coefficient to the matrix ?

When we use `\n` in print we do a line break, is there any way to reverse it by other print in order to come back to the initial position? In the picture added I would like to come back to the white rectangle.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can randomly access different portions of a Unix-like system's terminal text screen using the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses)  terminal control module. On other systems, like Windows, you will need to install an emulator (there are several available I believe).

Comment: Mathieu: Hope it helps you do what's needed. Those arrows you were seeing in your other question (and the rest of what was being printed) look like ANSI terminal escape sequences (the kind a program using `curses` might generate) btw.

Comment: Hello again @martineau and thank you very much for your help. Indeed I can use curses terminal. However I do not know how to plot some points representing the matrice coefficients and then ask to the user to select each coefficient. As our professor was using print formatting to locate the posito

Comment: Mathieu: Sorry I don't really understand your latest follow-on question — I am also not a `curses` expert — so suggest you ask a whole new question focused on that topic alone.

Comment: Hello @martineau, thank you very much for your help. I have found a way to solve my issue. Indeed by importing deinit and init from colorama I can manage the formating of print and print at a specific position in the terminal. Please, see just below a link in case anyone would be interested in : https://pypi.org/project/colorama/